# Why is my keyboard is not responding to touch when using Whats App?

Tags: iphone

The keyboard of my iPhone 6 is often blocked and does not respond to touch when I'm using Whats App, so I'm unable to write messages or reply back.

Comment: Have you used a jailbreak on your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the Whats App application first and re-downloading it. Also try using the original iOS keyboard if you are using a 3rd party keyboard